# PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0

Tags: c#, postsharp

After a recent updated to Windows 8.1, my VS 2013 no longer compiles my solution.

```
Error   1   Unhandled exception (2.1.7.35, 32 bit, CLR 4.0, Release): PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. [Public key mismatch]
============ PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================
LOG: Finding the assembly with binding identity 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
LOG: Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' because this file was explicitly added to the search path.
LOG: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' has identity 'mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089, processorarchitecture=msil'.
LOG: File 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\mscorlib.dll' does not match the reference.
...
LOG: The assembly 'mscorlib_7' was not found.
===============================================================
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.GetAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName, BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyRefDeclaration.GetAssemblyEnvelope()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.GetTypeDefinition(BindingOptions bindingOptions)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.GetTypeDefinition()
   at ^I3av2ouCqwmI.^4+F3cylo(INamedType _0, INamedType _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.TypeRefDeclaration.^A9yFoe2uB3TC(ITypeSignature _0, BindingOptions _1)
   at ^I3av2ouCqwmI.^4+F3cylo(IMethodSignature _0, IMethodSignature _1, BindingOptions _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Binding.MethodSignatureComparer.Equals(IMethodSignature x, IMethodSignature y)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at ^/vWxD3eYDOIx.^wdkNIZCy[??0](^/fRRnkiTvxqu _0, ??0 _1, ^EyL1LQX01Ck8 _2, ^0RC0kpHqS6Uy _3, Dictionary`2 _4, Int32 _5, Int32 _6)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleWriter.SetMemberSignatureIndex(MemberRefDeclaration _0, ^EyL1LQX01Ck8 _1, ^0RC0kpHqS6Uy _2)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleWriter.WriteMemberRef(MemberRefDeclaration _0, MetadataToken _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleWriter.GetMappedDeclarationToken(MetadataDeclaration _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleWriter.SetMappedMetadataToken(MetadataDeclaration _0, UInt32* _1)
   at ^R00FfLNj7vE0.^rk33N/hO(OpCodeNumber _0, MetadataDeclaration _1)
   at ^R00FfLNj7vE0.EmitInstructionMethod(OpCodeNumber _0, IMethod _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Instruction.Write(BaseInstructionWriter writer, InstructionPrefixes allowedPrefixes)
   at ^zpGNRK5nUM9z.^x98p/iJs13L+(InstructionReader _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodBodyDeclaration.^uPrQJ6gs(InstructionBlock _0, IMethodBodyVisitor[] _1, MethodBodyVisitLevel _2, InstructionAction _3, InstructionReader _4, InstructionBlockExceptionHandlingKind _5)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodBodyDeclaration.^uPrQJ6gs(InstructionBlock _0, IMethodBodyVisitor[] _1, MethodBodyVisitLevel _2, InstructionAction _3, InstructionReader _4, InstructionBlockExceptionHandlingKind _5)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodBodyDeclaration.^uPrQJ6gs(InstructionBlock _0, IMethodBodyVisitor[] _1, MethodBodyVisitLevel _2, InstructionAction _3, InstructionReader _4, InstructionBlockExceptionHandlingKind _5)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.MethodBodyDeclaration.^uPrQJ6gs(InstructionBlock _0, IMethodBodyVisitor[] _1, MethodBodyVisitLevel _2, InstructionAction _3, InstructionReader _4, InstructionBlockExceptionHandlingKind _5)
   at ^zpGNRK5nUM9z.^e2BtLyuT(^Kh85h0nXrulm& _0, Int32& _1)
   at ^zpGNRK5nUM9z.^SkiT(^ceSOybcTEumb _0)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Binary.ModuleWriter.WriteMethodBodies(^ceSOybcTEumb _0, UInt32 _1)
   at ^Up6wxUIUnN6a.^VfvrABjR()
   at ^Up6wxUIUnN6a.^SkiT()
   at ^cyC/TYSlPGB/.^wvPm(^RtksFin57NJ8 _0, ^8gP93Xsl\+Imn _1)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.CompileTask.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
   at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
   at PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)  E:\Development.TFS\CopyTran\MAIN\CopyTran\CopyTran.CoreDatabase\POSTSHARP   CopyTran.CoreDatabase
```

Any ideas what could be causing this behavior? A windows 7 machine with same VS2013 and code, works just fine.

**UPDATE**

As soon as I added this code back, the compilation error re-appeared:

```
TypeMap[] allTypeMaps = Mapper.GetAllTypeMaps();
foreach (TypeMap typeMap in allTypeMaps)
{
    foreach (PropertyMap propertyMap in typeMap.GetPropertyMaps())
    {
        if ((propertyMap.SourceMember as PropertyInfo).PropertyType.Name !=
            propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType.Name)
        {
            _log.WarnFormat("Types not matching {0}.{1} <> {2}.{3}", typeMap.SourceType.Name,
            propertyMap.SourceMember.Name, typeMap.DestinationType.Name,
            propertyMap.DestinationProperty.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

_log is ILog from Log4Net, but it is used in other places without any issues.

Comment: What .NET version is set for the project 5.0, 4.5 or 4.0? Try setting 4.0 .NET version for the application using the library (if it is not already or if it is smaller than 4.x). Also try with different build platforms (x86 and AnyCPU).

Comment: ^I3av2ouCqwmI.^4+F3cylo(), what could possibly go wrong?  Ask your AOP vendor to talk to your obfuscator vendor.  Or the other way around.

Comment: @Darek remove the reference and add it again

Comment: Project is targeting .Net 4.0. Adding a search path to `<PostSharpSearchPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile1\</PostSharpSearchPath>` allowed me to compile again.

Comment: @KristianDamian remove PostSharp reference?

Comment: Note that you have a reference to a Silverlight/WP/PCL version of mscorlib. Not sure it's intended if your project targets .NET 4.0.

Comment: That's the thing, only when it is available in the search path, the project compiles. Puzzled... And the project is just a .Net 4.0 class library.

Comment: I continue changing the search path to other mscorlib versiosn. Made it all the way to version 4.0 in the .Net Framework directory. The solution continues to compile. Still puzzled.

Comment: I have removed the additional search path and it works again .. puzzled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had resolved this issue  (for a different assembly) on my .Net 4.5.1 project by adding the following to the

```
<DontImportPostSharp>True</DontImportPostSharp>
<PostSharpTargetFrameworkVersion>4.0</PostSharpTargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp 2.1 does not support Windows 8.1. The latest supported version is Windows 7. You should upgrade to PostSharp 3.1. Also, I see you're targeting PCLs, and PCL support has been greatly improved in PostSharp 3.1.

Comment: It was working fine until recently, and I am not targeting PCL. However, based on the internet wisdom (Google) and your support site, adding this search path `<PostSharpSearchPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\Profile\Profile1\</PostSharpSearchPath>` allowed me to compile again.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem again but upgrading to Autofac 4 wasn't possible because of a solution locked into MVC4.

Solution this time was to copy `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\BindingMaps` from my local machine to the build server

Comment: That works for my local. Copied it from my colleague's computer.
Since it was a legacy project, decided to leave it without further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on our TeamCity build server.

After trying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198196/1141876) to no avail, I went through the referenced assemblies of the broken project and inspected them with [IlSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) to check which one had the `mscorlib 2.0.5.0` reference

The culprit was `Autofac 3.3.0.0`.

Updating the nuget package to `Autofac 4.8.1.0` solved the problem.