# PostSharp not building on TeamCity: Cannot find assembly mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, postsharp

PostSharp will build on local dev machine, it will not build on the TeamCity server, the error is:

```
unknown error PS0264: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'.
```

Here is an excerpt from the build log:

```
[13:38:22][PostSharp30] Merging assembly binding policy files.
[13:38:22][PostSharp30] Executing "C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\5.0.43\bin.Release\postsharp-net40-x86-native.exe" <REMOVED SENSITIVE INFORMATION>
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: Detailed log for the next error:
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG: Finding reference assembly with binding identity 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e' in the Reference context.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Found file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll', identity='mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089', ProcessorArchitecture=NoPlatform.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Reference mismatch for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' [PublicKeyMismatch].
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Found file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll', identity='mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089', ProcessorArchitecture=NoPlatform.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Reference mismatch for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' [PublicKeyMismatch].
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Found file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll', identity='mscorlib, version=4.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b77a5c561934e089', ProcessorArchitecture=NoPlatform.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  Reference mismatch for 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll' [PublicKeyMismatch].
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: LOG:  The assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e, retargetable=yes' was not found.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown : verbose PS0265: .
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] unknown error PS0264: Cannot find assembly 'mscorlib, version=2.0.5.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=7cec85d7bea7798e'. [Public key mismatch]. Build your project with detailed verbosity to see the assembly loading log.
[13:38:25][PostSharp30] C:\BuildAgent\work\be9df088c843a629\src\packages\PostSharp.5.0.43\build\PostSharp.targets(314, 5): The process C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\5.0.43\bin.Release\postsharp-net40-x86-native.exe exited with code 11.
[13:38:25][Step 4/5] Process exited with code 1
```

### Update

After comparing file (local vs build server) in C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\InstalledFrameworks, I can see that my local machine has these additional frameworks:

```
  <Framework Identifier=".NETFramework" Version="4.7.1">
    <ReferenceAssemblies>
      <Directory Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.7.1\" />
    </ReferenceAssemblies>
  </Framework>
  <Framework Identifier=".NETPortable" Version="4.0">
    <ReferenceAssemblies>
      <Directory Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.0\" />
    </ReferenceAssemblies>
  </Framework>
  <Framework Identifier=".NETPortable" Version="4.5">
    <ReferenceAssemblies>
      <Directory Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\" />
    </ReferenceAssemblies>
  </Framework>
  <Framework Identifier=".NETPortable" Version="4.6">
    <ReferenceAssemblies>
      <Directory Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.6\" />
    </ReferenceAssemblies>
  </Framework>
  <Framework Identifier=".NETPortable" Version="5.0">
    <ReferenceAssemblies>
      <Directory Location="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v5.0\" />
    </ReferenceAssemblies>
  </Framework>
```

Comment: TC agent doesn't have installed something that your local machine has. I'd start by comparing .NET framework versions. Does your local build still work if you disable PostSharp extensions (if any)? What is the target framework of the PostSharp Nuget package?

Comment: I removed import of PostSharp.targets in the csproj file, build still worked on local. Target framework of nuget package is net45. [This suggests](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/questions/1086-postsharpsdkcodemodelassemblyloadexception-cannot-find-assembly-mscorlib#comment_37222081) installing Microsoft Build Tools 2013 and Portable Library Reference Assemblies, both are installed on build server.

Comment: target this location vs program x86, C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(version number)\mscorlib.dll. See for reference; https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e61ca938-486c-4dbb-834b-6ba15c74f9f9/mscorlibexe-path?forum=csharpgeneral. If you unsure which versions are installed then refer to article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/how-to-determine-which-versions-are-installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build server required Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6:

1. Download & install [Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727)
2. Extract `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6\PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\`

Note: Character casing of the folder ".NETPortable" must be as defined. Use mkdir to create folders starting with a period symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Copying `C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\BindingMaps` from my local machine to the build server worked for me (Postsharp 4.2.19)

Comment: Amazingly this worked for me after a multitude of other failures